# jdbcTemplate.query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse) does not return any resultset

Tags: java, java-7, jdbctemplate, spring-3

I am in the process of converting creation of connection to use JdbcTemplate class which handles the creation and release of resources. 
One of the implementation shown below is not returning me a resultset though the original one for the same query returns me records. I converted the below code

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement(strQuery, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ps.setLong(1, getId());
objRs = ps.executeQuery();
```

to the one shown below. The reason I used a StreamingStatementCreator was because I needed to set
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE and ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY.

```
objRs = (ResultSet) jdbcTemplate.query(new StreamingStatementCreator(strQuery),
        new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
                preparedStatement.setLong(1, getId());
            }
        }, new CustomResultSetExtractor());
```

```
public class CustomResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<ResultSet>{
    public ResultSet extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with these methods. I tried to look for examples and I feel the code is correct by maybe I missing something. The first case returns me value in objRs and the second returns me nothing.

Comment: you should add code of `CustomResultSetExtractor` class

Answer (score 1):

Method `query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)` Does not returns `ResultSet`. It calls second parameter with `ResultSet` as argument and returns object that was returned by it.

So you shoud process `ResultSet` in `CustomResultSetExtractor` and return onther object as a result of processing.

Comment: I am using customResultSetExtrator for multiple select statements. So I want to return the resultset and process it for the different select statements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clue by Alexander, made use of the ColumnMapRowMapper to iterate the result set. Since I wanted a generic solution that I could use for all my queries, instead of processing the resultset in my CustomResultSetExtractor or create separate classes. 
I am adding the code here so that anyone else who comes across this same situation may find it useful.

```
public class CustomResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<Object>{

    private RowMapper<Map<String, Object>> mapper;

    public CustomResultSetExtractor(ColumnMapRowMapper mapper) {
       this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        int row = 0;
        while(rs.next()){  
            Map<String, Object> o = (Map<String, Object>)mapper.mapRow(rs, row++);
            list.add(o);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```